# two derived class of a subclass but with two return type

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have a super Class (A) and two sub Class (B ,C)

an abstract Function in A have two difference return type in B and C!

How i have to Declare these??

*return type is important*

```
class A {                              //Super Class
public:
  A();
  virtual (some Type) QWERTY() = 0;
};

class B : public A {                   //Sub Class
public:
  B();
  double QWERTY();
};

class C : public A {                   //Sub Class
public:
  C();
  unsigned int QWERTY();
};
```

Comment: That's not possible. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – what is the actual problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: You can't. The declaration in the base type and definition in child types MUST all return the same type. So you'll have to use a type that can either be a `unsigned int` or a `double`. `std::variant<>` would fit that bill.

Comment: I think this is impossible. You can't do polymorphism with a generic type because function `unsigned int QWERTY()` is different from function `double QWERTY()`.  This is not override

Comment: @molbdnilo It's our uni Exercise and i'v to call sub Class function with super Class pointer but sub Classes return type are difference!!! can help me with other solution or other algorithm??!?!?!

Comment: @MrOutadi If the class `B` and `C` are provided to you, then you'll have to go through a `dynamic_cast<>` to invoke the respective `QWERTY()` functions.

Comment: Then either you or your university must have misunderstood something. (There is one possibility – returning references or pointers to related classes – but primitive types are out. Does your exercise really ask for `unsigned int` and `double` specifically?)

Answer (score 0):

> i'v to call sub Class function with super Class pointer

Since the functions are different in each sub-classes, you'll have to access them from pointers to those sub-classes.

This is exactly the kind of situation where `dynamic_cast<>` can help: it can conditionally convert a pointer from a base class to a sub-class if and only if it happens to be of the correct type:

```
void foo(A* a_ptr) {
  B* b_ptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(a_ptr);
  C* c_ptr = dynamic_cast<C*>(a_ptr);

  if(b_ptr) {
    b_ptr->QWERTY();
  }

  if(c_ptr) {
    c_ptr->QWERTY();
  }
}

It's, however, worth mentioning that this is some pretty ugly code, and might be suitable to solve the quiz you are presenting us, but in a normal environment, there are some design reevaluation that would happen before going to implement things this way.
```